# JavaScript/AngularJS: converting array value to Integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can't seem to find an answer for this. I have a select box which when clicked on maps to my model -

```
<select class="form-control"
        size="8"
        ng-model="Info.FolderId"
        ng-options="Folder.Id as Folder.Name for Folder in AvailableFolders">
</select>
```

So the model holds the Id of the folder. However that Id will not be stored as "1" or "2" it will be stored as [1] or [2].

Is there an easy way of converting this using something like ng-change, or an easier way I should be going about doing this?

Comment: What does the Folder data structure look like? If Folder.Id is an array, you'll  bind Info.FolderId to an array.

Comment: It's declared like 'FolderId: 0', so no array. I guess this must be the default for selects.

Comment: I don't think this is the default for selects in Angular, I've never had this problem. Can you provide a codepen or something similar and show me what AvailableFolders looks like?

Comment: Ah, this was my fault. I was using the 'multiple' attribute for the select which will obviously cause this, it just wasn't pasted into my question -_-

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<select class="form-control"
        size="8"
        ng-model="Info.FolderId"
        ng-options="Folder.Id[0] as Folder.Name for Folder in AvailableFolders">
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, when you try and select something it will always force a select on the first item in the select